# C# String split based on the delimiter pattern [,]

Tags: c#

I am having trouble splitting the below text. Is there any easier way to split this.

the input will be either like

`"1[,]Group A[,]2[,]Group B[,]3[,]Group C[,]4[,]Group D"`

OR

`"a[,]Group A[,]b[,]Group B[,]c[,]Group C[,]d[,]Group D"`

OR

`"a)[,]Group A[,]b)[,]Group B[,]c)[,]Group C[,]d)[,]Group D"`

Or Sometimes it will be like below text. How do I identify the absence of above pattern as well

`"1 Group A[,]2 Group B[,]3 Group C[,]4 Group D"`

Expected output

> Group A 
> Group B 
> Group C 
> Group D

Comment: Seems like a case for our good old friend [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0). So something like `string[] splits = input.Split("[,]");` should work.

Comment: ..Or `string[] splits = Regex.Split(input, @"\[,\]");`

Comment: Do you want to split on `[,]` or on `[,]` preceded by a digit or on `[,]` followed by a digit? The requirement is not clear.

Comment: You can solve this better with regex expressions. as Dmitry point out. A nice tool for learning and testing your string: http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm

Comment: split on single alphanumeric preceded by [,] and followed by [,] . eg. [,]2[,]   or [,]1[,]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cooked up this method real quick with a pseudo pattern check:

```cs
static void pattern(string input)
{
    string[] splits = input.Split(new[] { "[,]" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    if (splits.Length < 2)
        return;

    //pseudo pattern check
    char[] patternStart = splits[0].ToCharArray();
    for(int i = 2; i < splits.Length; i+=2)
    {
        patternStart[0]++;
        if (!patternStart.SequenceEqual(splits[i]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("pattern fail");
            return;
        }
    }

    foreach (string entry in splits.Where((s, i) => i % 2 == 1))
        Console.WriteLine(entry);
}
```

The pattern check if based on the idea that it is always the first character in the patter that is increasing and it will always be something progressing by 1 in the ASCII table (e.g. a,b,c or A,B,C or 1,2,3)

Running this with the provided patterns:

```cs
pattern("1[,]Group A[,]2[,]Group B[,]3[,]Group C[,]4[,]Group D");
Console.WriteLine();
pattern("a[,]Group A[,]b[,]Group B[,]c[,]Group C[,]d[,]Group D");
Console.WriteLine();
pattern("a)[,]Group A[,]b)[,]Group B[,]c)[,]Group C[,]d)[,]Group D");
Console.WriteLine();
pattern("1 Group A[,]2 Group B[,]3 Group C[,]4 Group D");
Console.WriteLine();
```

yields

```
Group A
Group B
Group C
Group D

Group A
Group B
Group C
Group D

Group A
Group B
Group C
Group D

pattern fail
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of splitting your string, you can try just picking the parts you want out of the string:

```cs
var r = new Regex("Group [A-Z]");
var m = r.Matches(inputstring);
var result = m.Select(t => t.Value).ToList();
```

That will match any "Group" followed by a single uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your group names must be longer than two characters, you can simply use:

```
var groups = input.Replace("[,]","\0").Split( '\0' ).Where( x => x.Length > 2 );
var output = string.Join( " ", groups );
```

Or

```
var groups = input.Split( "[,]" ).Where( x => x.Length > 2 );
var output = string.Join( " ", groups );
```

If your group names might be 2 or fewer characters, your requirements are not complete, as there is ambiguity. For example, with this input:

```
a)[,]a)[,]b)[,]b)
```

The output could be either

```
a) b)
```

Or

```
a) a) b) b)
```

...so you will need to come up with a rule to distinguish the text you wish to keep from the text you wish to discard.

Comment: @JohnG I was also confused at first but turns out that [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0#System_String_Split_System_String_System_StringSplitOptions_) (which is available in .NET Core 2.0 and above) has an _optional_ second parameter (making `.Split(string)` legal). That said, `.Split(string)` will _not_ work in .NET Framework, obviously (which should probably be noted).

Comment: @41686d6564 … Ahh it did not know this. Thank you for the clarification and I stand corrected.